# Same initialization to a set of controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let say I have 50 controllers and 25 of them need the same initialization code which is somewhat long such as:

`$scope.a = 1;
$scope.b = "a";
...
$scope.zzz = "xyz";`

What is the best way? I don't want to copy and paste in each beginning of 25 controllers? I don't want to put in 25 of the views' `ng-init` either.

**UPDATE 1**

I am using `angular-ui-router` and each controller is per state per view/template. Maybe there is a way to do this in the `angular-ui-router` more DRY?

Comment: Make a function that is registered on the $scope and gets called 25 times?

Comment: have the initialization code in a service and then inject that service in all the controllers in which you require

Answer (score 1):

The service example what I mentioned can be achieved like this:

```
angular.service('yourService',function() {
    return {
          setInitialValues: function(scope) {
              scope.a = 22;
              //All your Initial values
          }
    }
});
```

And in the controller inject the services and pass your scope to the controller and set it over their. This will work in the scope of Angular and nothing is global over here

Comment: One more way is to use the resolve property in the angular-ui-router however in that one as well you would require to repeat that in all the views which would have the 25 controllers. So service is I think the best way forward.

Comment: you can use $rootScope as well however that will be used in other controllers which DOES NOT require this initialization (as it is global) so that option is also not good in this case

Answer (score 0):

You simply declare a function

```
var f = function($scope) {
    //Init stuff here
}
```

Then use it in all 25 controlers writen under this text.

//controler1 init..... 
    f($scope);

Comment: Then `f` would be a global variable. Is there a way to contain within angular itself?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your project will be going big someday.

I suggest the best way is to use a Class.js like library.

Create a .init() and .destroy() to all objects that will be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prototypal inheritance. Think of it like having a base or abstract class, that your other classes inherit from.

```
var BaseCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.a = 1;
    ... 
});

var AnotherCtrl = function($scope) {
    BaseCtrl.call(this, $scope);
    ....
});
AnotherCtrl.prototype = Object.create(BaseCtrl.prototype, {});
```

The syntax would be a little different if you are using ControllerAs.